# @Transcational test class affects how transactional service layer works

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing integration tests for my Spring boot app Rest controller.

When I annotate the test class with `@Transactional` it doesn't work as expected, and when I remove the annotation it passes fine.

1. Does using `@Transactional` on a test class mean absolutely 
   nothing gets written to the db ? My other tests work fine !
   They do more or less the same job. They write/update/read but this
   test tests a delete endpoint.
2. If annotating a test class with @Transactional means there's no control on data persistence, why do people even use it on their tests ? I injected entity manager to the test class and called `flush` and `clear`, it didn't help.
3. Even if the data is not written to the db, they are persisted, right ? Doesn't calling `repository.delete` should delete that item from the persistence context ?
4. The code that doesn't affect the db (delete) is located in the Service layer. It's called from within the Controller that I'm testing, not the test class. I expected it to work regardless of the fact that test class is annotated with `@Transacational` or not.

**Note** Service layer is `@Transactional`

This is in the service layer and is called by the controller. It's not called form within the test.

```
public void delete(long groupId, String username) {
    Group group = this.loadById(groupId);
    User user = userService.loadByUsername(username);
    groupRepository.delete(groupId);
}
```

**Edit 1**

The code for the test that fails:

```
/*
 * Deleting a group shouldn't delete the members of that group
 */
@Test
public void testDeleteGroupWithMembers() throws Exception {
    Principal mockPrincipal = Mockito.mock(Principal.class);
    Mockito.when(mockPrincipal.getName()).thenReturn(DUMMY_USERNAME);

    User admin = userTestingUtil.createUser(DUMMY_USERNAME, DUMMY_USER_NAME, null, null);
    Group group = groupTestingUtil.createGroup(DUMMY_GROUP_NAME, DUMMY_GROUP_DESCRIPTION, DUMMY_IMAGE_ID, admin);

    User member = userTestingUtil.createUser("test1@test.test", "testUser1" , null, null);
    group.addMember(member);

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .delete(GROUP_ENDPOINT_URL + group.getId())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .principal(mockPrincipal);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
    int status = response.getStatus();
    String content = response.getContentAsString();
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong response status", 200, status);
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong response content", "", content);
    //This test fails, as the group is not yet deleted from the repo
    Assert.assertEquals("there should be no group left", 0, Lists.newArrayList(groupRepository.findAll()).size());
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong number of users exist", 2, Lists.newArrayList(userRepository.findAll()).size());
    Assert.assertTrue("admin shouldn't get deleted when deleting a group", userRepository.findById(admin.getId()) != null);
    Assert.assertTrue("group members shouldn't get deleted when deleting a group", userRepository.findById(member.getId()) != null);
}
```

The code for the test that works in the same test class:

```
@Test
public void testCreateGroup() throws Exception {
    Principal mockPrincipal = Mockito.mock(Principal.class);
    Mockito.when(mockPrincipal.getName()).thenReturn(DUMMY_USERNAME);

    User user = userTestingUtil.createUser(DUMMY_USERNAME, DUMMY_USER_NAME, null, null);

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put(NAME_FIELD_NAME, DUMMY_GROUP_NAME);
    jo.put(DESCRIPTION_FIELD_NAME, DUMMY_GROUP_DESCRIPTION);
    jo.put(IMAGE_FIELD_NAME, DUMMY_IMAGE);
    String testGroupJson = jo.toString();

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post(GROUP_ENDPOINT_URL).content(testGroupJson)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .principal(mockPrincipal);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
    int status = response.getStatus();
    String content = response.getContentAsString();

    List<Group> createdGroups = Lists.newArrayList(groupRepository.findAll());
    Group createdGroup = createdGroups.get(0);

    Assert.assertEquals("wrong response status", 200, status);
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong response content", "", content);
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong number of groups created", 1, createdGroups.size());
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong group name", DUMMY_GROUP_NAME, createdGroup.getName());
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong group description", DUMMY_GROUP_DESCRIPTION, createdGroup.getDescription());
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong admin is assigned to the group", user.getId(), createdGroup.getAdmin().getId());
    List<Group> groups = userTestingUtil.getOwnedGroups(user.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong number of groups created for the admin", 1, groups.size());
    Assert.assertEquals("wrong group is assigned to the admin", user.getOwnedGroups().get(0).getId(), createdGroup.getAdmin().getId());
    Assert.assertTrue("image file was not created", CommonUtils.getImageFile(createdGroup.getImageId()).exists());
}
```

Create and Delete methods in the `GroupService` :

```
public void create(String groupName, String description, String image, String username) throws IOException {
    User user = userService.loadByUsername(username);
    Group group = new Group();
    group.setAdmin(user);
    group.setName(groupName);
    group.setDescription(description);
    String imageId = CommonUtils.decodeBase64AndSaveImage(image);
    if (imageId != null) {
        group.setImageId(imageId);
    }
    user.addOwnedGroup(group);
    groupRepository.save(group);
    logger.debug("Group with name " + group.getName() + " and id " + group.getId() + " was created");
}

public void delete(long groupId, String username) {
    Group group = this.loadById(groupId);
    User user = userService.loadByUsername(username);
    validateAdminAccessToGroup(group, user);
    groupRepository.delete(groupId);
    logger.debug("Group with id " + groupId + " was deleted");
}
```

The code for the rest controller:

```
/*
 * Create a group
 */
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody PostGroupDto groupDto, Principal principal, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    createGroupDtoValidator.validate(groupDto, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException(result.getFieldError().getCode());
    }
    groupService.create(groupDto.getName(), groupDto.getDescription(), groupDto.getImage(), principal.getName());
}

/*
 * Delete a group
 */
@RequestMapping(path = "/{groupId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void delete(@PathVariable long groupId, Principal principal) {
    groupService.delete(groupId, principal.getName());
}
```

**Edit 2**

I tried deleting `User` instead of `Group` and it doesn't work either. In the same method (`delete` method of the Group Service layer) creating a group works, but deleting does not !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging around for some time, I found out what the issue was. 
The `User` class has a list of `Group` entities. In the `delete` method of the `Group` service layer I had to remove the deleted group from the list of groups a user points to. It is disappointing that the persistent context doesn't throw any exception for it.

Comment: To be a little blunt, your suggestion that the persistence context should throw an exception, indicates that you have not fully understood how it works.  Typically you would not remove the `Group` from `User` unless a transaction is already started (and the use i loaded) before the delete method is called. Because, if `User` is already loaded, it is best to keep the bidirectional relations in sync with the database, otherwise the caller will have to call `em.refresh(user)` to see that the group is no longer in the `User's` list (assuming the correct cascade).

Answer (score 6):

It is rolled back when test is annotated with `@Transactional`.

> 1. Does using @Transactional on a test class mean absolutely nothing gets written to the db ? My other tests work fine ! They do more or less the same job.

Please post your other tests for more details.

> 2. If annotating a test class with @Transactional means there's no control on data persistence, why do people even use it on their tests
>      ?

To prevent filling database with test data.

> 3. Even if the data is not written to the db, they are persisted, right ? Doesn't calling repository.delete should delete that item from
>      the persistence context ?

Where do you check if an item was deleted from the persistence context?

> 4. The code that doesn't affect the db (delete) is located in the Service layer. It's called from within the Controller that I'm
>      testing, not the test class. I expected it to work regardless of the
>      fact that test class is annotated with @Transacational or not.

Every method in the test is wrapped with Spring transaction so data may be not committed until the test ends.

Check for detailed answers:

- [Should my tests be @Transactional?](https://www.marcobehler.com/2014/06/25/should-my-tests-be-transactional/)
- [Spring boot test @Transactional not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658630/spring-boot-test-transactional-not-saving)

Comment: I know it's rolled back, but it's rolled back after the test finishes running. Not in the middle of it. Otherwise any test annotated with `@Transactional` wouldn't work at all.

Comment: I added some more details to the question.

Comment: It may be that @Transactional test does not commit data / hit DB too.

Comment: I updated the post with the code for the test (transactional), service layer (transactional), and the controller (not transactional)

Comment: I put a comment on the Assert that fails.

Answer (score 1):

From a broader perspective I think you may be using the wrong tool for the job.

Tests need to be isolated from each other so the the order of tests run doesn't have an impact on the results.

This is achieved in JUnit for example by creating a new instance of the test class for every test method of it that is to be executed.

For Integration tests that are testing the logic *within a specific transaction* this can be achieved by starting the transaction on test start and then rolling it back on the end of the test. So the database doesn't carry along any test specific data and is therefore ready to be used by the next test.

For testing a rest controller another approach is possibly required. You probably start a transaction somewhere within that controller and not before the actual rest controller code is invoked when it's running in your production environment. You might have cases where controllers cause communication with other systems than the db (if these are allowed in your controller tests). Or you might have cases where multiple transactions are done within the same rest controller invocation or a transaction that uses a non-default transaction isolation and so on. These cases won't work with the default behaviour of `@Transactional` test cases.

So you might want to reconsider your testing approach and define what the test scope of each set of tests is. Then based on these scopes you can define a strategy on how isolating the tests in each scope is achieved. Then for each test run apply the appropriate strategy.