# How to save data in H2 database with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I want to make a desktop application using JavaFx, Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA with H2 as my database . The problem is that I am trying to run Junit to save data locally in a directory but every time I run Junit the data is being lost.

My `application.properties` file;

```
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS                    
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test; 
DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

My test case;

```
HotelEntity hotelEntity = new HotelEntity(1, "Name", "Password", "MobileNumber", "email");
hotelDao.save(hotelEntity);
System.out.println("Hotel Dao--");
List<HotelEntity> hotelEntities = hotelDao.findAll();
System.out.println(hotelEntities.size());
```

It print the list size is 1 but when i run test case again like this

```
List<HotelEntity> hotelEntities = hotelDao.findAll();
System.out.println(hotelEntities.size());
```

It print the list size is 0

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please let me know, I can help more if it was not

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that during tests, any data you create will not be committed without proper transactional definition. My suggestions are;

- Separate test h2 db from production h2 db, very dangerous to use same for both. You can use `jdbc:h2:mem:test` for testing, and `jdbc:h2:mem:main` for the production db for example.
- Add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` for production db configuration, and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` for test. Since you don't want to keep test db persisted.
- If you are trying to commit data from test logic, you'd need to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658630/spring-boot-test-transactional-not-saving)

Also to be able to access `h2` between sessions, you'd need to use an extra option, namely [`AUTO_RECONNECT`](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_reconnect), can you add them to your url?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
```

Comment: Actually i want to use it with JavaFx

Comment: @RaviDeveloper even with or without JavaFx this answer is still applicable, if you are content with it can you accept it? Thanks =)

Comment: As our discussion i tried to use call main method and when close the application the data had been lost.

Comment: @RaviDeveloper did you try using `AUTO_RECONNECT` ?